# juju bootstrap hangs forever at "Attempting to connect to 10.X.X.X:22"

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I am installing openstack Autopilot as per the below URL
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/autopilot

After executing the conjure-up --bootstrap-to  this command
juju bootstrap hangs at

"Attempting to connect to 10.X.X.X:22"

Kinldy help us to solve

Comment: Please describe your network topology and configuration